# $_GET not being set

Tags: php, get

**When printing `$_GET` there is an error:**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _GET
```

**Testing code:**

```
echo "query string: ".($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
print_r($_GET);
```

**The testing URL:**

```
http://localhost/?foo=bar
```

**The resulting output is this:**

```
query string: foo=bar
Notice: Undefined variable: _GET in C:\Users\DGmoN\Google Drive\Code\Web\CMS2\index.php on line 3
```

Comment: where do you set the $_GET??

Comment: @JohnConde its all there, under "testing code" its all there is to index.php

Comment: Did you forget to put a `$` in front of `_GET`?

Comment: @Anandhunadesh As far as I know it should be set by the server, I never touch it. I just have those 2 lines that are excecuted

Comment: @KevinP nope, its there, under testing code, the 2 lines, thats whats being excecuted

Comment: you are getting the error bcz it is not being set. Just simple as that.

Comment: @Anandhunadesh where should I set it?

Comment: It should be set automatically by your testing URL that you are using.  What is your server setup? Apache? Other?

Comment: @Anandhunadesh the query string sets the GET parameters

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: @j08691 mamp apache out of the box. there is no .htaccess and I have cleared my browser cash

Comment: Try `$_REQUEST` instead?

Comment: @Derek php v 7.1.5

Comment: @Derek ok, that seemed to work, but why is this a problem to start with?

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73554?